# TLS or HTTPS with noDelay?

Tags: node.js

I've noticed that sockets and `HTTP` have option to set `noDelay`, but there is no such an option over `SSL` with `TLS` or `HTTPS` ... is there any reason for that? How can I make a connection over `SSL` with `noDelay` socket flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tls.TLSSocket`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket) is a subclass of `net.Socket`. So you can call [`setNoDelay`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay) directly.